# With JQ search multiple key: value pairs and replace with define variable already

Tags: json, jq

I have a couple of json files and both or one of the keys below, might exist or none exists.

```
{
  "parent1": {
    "parent1key": "parent1value"
  },
  "parent2": {
    "parent2key": "parent2value"
  }

}
```

if both the key: pairs always exist, I could use

`jq --arg parent1keyarg $MyVAL1 --arg parent2keyarg $MyVAL2 '(..|objects|select(.parent1key ).parent1key ) |= $parent1keyarg | (..|objects|select(.parent2key).parent2key) |= $parent2keyarg ' jsonfile.json`

1. I want to find the `parent1key` and `parent2key` and if found one or both, then replace them with a variable that's generated during runtime. If none of the key: values are found just ignore it rather than troughing up an error.
2. I want to use `jq --arg` instead of bash `if` conditions, just to ensure the JSON formatting is accurate ( or jq is interesting to me ).

how could we write conditions in JQ is what I'm unable to figure out from jq manuals.

Appreciate it if anyone could help me with this.

Thanks!

Comment: @inian - please undelete your excellent and potentially useful answer!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple `walk/1` expression would be sufficient to check for existence of the key recursively. It can be further improved by making it a function.

```
def replace(k; v):
   walk(if type == "object" and has(k) then .[k] = v else . end);

replace("parent1key"; "foo") | replace("parent2key"; "bar")
```

The first argument to `replace` takes the key name for which the value is to be replaced. Simply pipe any numbers of keys and the associated values that you want to change.

Answer (score 2):

From your description, it would seem the following would suffice:

```
if has("parent1key") then .parent1key = $a
else . end 
| if has("parent2key") then .parent2key = $b
  else . end
```

If you need more than that, then I’d use the above with `walk`:

```
walk(if type=="object"
     then if has("parent1key") then .parent1key = $a
          else . end 
          | if has("parent2key") then .parent2key = $b
            else . end
     else . end)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
( .parent1.parent1key | select( . ) ) |= $parent1keyarg |
( .parent2.parent2key | select( . ) ) |= $parent2keyarg
```